# Javascript link in image

Tags: javascript

What I have are 3 images but are not online , I need to get link these three pictures to go on different pages !
each image each link

```js
var images = [
  'image/dragao1.jpg',
  'image/dragao2.jpg',
  'image/dragao3.jpg'
];

function slideShowForward() {
  images.push(images.shift());
  document.getElementById('imagesP').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0] + ')';
}

function slideShowBack() {
  images.unshift(images.pop());
  document.getElementById('imagesP').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0] + ')';
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesP" style=" border: 1px solid black; height: 200px; width:750px;">
  <div id="form">
    <input type="button" value="previous" onclick="slideShowBack();" style="width: 39px; height: 34px;" />
    <input type="button" value="next" onclick="slideShowForward();" style="width: 39px; height: 34px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It’s hard to understand what you mean. Is `#imagesP` your `<a>` element? Is your link somewhere else? Where’s the rest of your HTML?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, edit the snippet and put your HTML _there_, **not in the comments**. There’s still no mention of a link anywhere. What do you mean by _“I have to put the images link”_?

Comment: You need to add an onclick to the div if you want to click an image to go somewhere

Comment: what I want is when the person clicks on the image and go to a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var images = [
  'http://cinemacomrapadura.com.br/imagens/2014/01/20140127-como-treinar-seu-dragao1.jpg',
  'http://cinemacomrapadura.com.br/imagens/2014/01/20140127-como-treinar-seu-dragao2.jpg',
  'http://br.web.img2.acsta.net/c_520_690/newsv7/15/02/06/17/22/496087.jpg'
];
var hrefs=["http://www.google.com","http://www.msdn.com","http://www.yahoo.com"]

function slideShowForward() {
  images.push(images.shift());
  hrefs.push(hrefs.shift());
  document.getElementById('imagesP').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0] + ')';
  document.getElementById('imagesP').setAttribute(href,hrefs[0]);
}

function slideShowBack() {
  images.unshift(images.pop());
  hrefs.unshift(hrefs.pop());
  document.getElementById('imagesP').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0] + ')';
  document.getElementById('imagesP').setAttribute(href,hrefs[0]);
}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('imagesP').onclick=function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target||e.srcElement;
    if (tgt.tagName.toLowerCase()=="input") e.preventDefault();
    else location=this.getAttribute("href");
  }
}
```

```css
#imagesP { border: 1px solid black; height: 200px; width:750px;  background-image: url(http://br.web.img2.acsta.net/c_520_690/newsv7/15/02/06/17/22/496087.jpg)}
```

```html
<div id="imagesP" href="http://www.google.com">
  <div id="form">
    <input type="button" value="previous" onclick="slideShowBack();" style="width: 39px; height: 34px;" />
    <input type="button" value="next" onclick="slideShowForward();" style="width: 39px; height: 34px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Google and others might not run here in the snippet due to security - but also I used your strange array handling to not change too much. Should work though